# Xampp with MacOS using libsodium

Tags: macos, cryptography, libsodium

I using xampp on my macbook. And use the project on my Windows machine too.
I use the library of Crypto which using libsodium. I installed libsodium on the macbook (Windows I didnt) but my encryption dont seems to work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Do I need to set `extension=libsodium` in php.ini? Do I need to set a libsodium file somewhere in my xampp folder or should it be taken by the OS only? I have no clue anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue and took time to figure out for the old php version.
libsodium comes with php 7.1 and onwards

1. brew install libsodium
2. sudo pecl install -f libsodium
3. Add extension in the php.ini file, extension=sodium.so

Comment: I will test this this later to day. Your suggestion may work if I read it. Step 2 is no where been written. Thx anyway. Step to PHP 7.0 (there is libsodium available) will be the best option without installing stuff

Comment: for anyone use xampp 7.4.8 libsodium won't load, simply downgrade to 7.3.20 . It's a bug with 7.4.8