# About problem in installing ext-sodium * for installing lcobucci/jwt 4.3.0 and kreait/firebase-tokens 4.3.0 for laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, libsodium

createtoken(""); is not working in my laravel project... where i have deleted vendor file and done `composer install`:

i am getting :

```
Problem 1
- lcobucci/jwt is locked to version 4.3.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
- lcobucci/jwt 4.3.0 requires ext-sodium * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sodium extension.
Problem 2
- lcobucci/jwt 4.3.0 requires ext-sodium * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sodium extension.
- kreait/firebase-tokens 4.3.0 requires lcobucci/jwt ^4.3.0|^5.0 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[4.3.0].
- kreait/firebase-tokens is locked to version 4.3.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

then i did  `sudo pecl install libsodium`

but i am getting :

> janammaharjan@Janams-MacBook-Air laravel-uat % sudo pecl install libsodium
> WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update
> pecl.php.net" to update
> pecl/libsodium requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0, version <= 8.0.99), installed version
> is 8.2.4
> No valid packages found
> install failed

I have php version 8.2.4

i tried installing xampp with php 8.0.28 but it is not helping can anyone please help me on this ?

```
sudo pecl install -f libsodium
```

i am getting :
configure: error: wrong libsodium lib version (< 1.0.8) or lib not found
ERROR: `/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/libsodium/configure --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php-config' failed

Comment: try with this commands:

```sudo apt-get install php-sodium
```
```sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: i am getting : sudo: apt-get: command not found i am in mac macOs Sonoma 14.3

Comment: may be it can solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50356668/xampp-with-macos-using-libsodium

Comment: From https://www.php.net/manual/en/sodium.installation.php *As of PHP 7.2.0 this extension is bundled with PHP* so something is up with your PHP installation or configuration. Check you php.ini or related configuration directories for hints. The PECL extension is really only meant for PHP versions before 7.2 even though it technically supports up to PHP 8

Comment: @VinodPatidar in force install am again getting 
configure: error: wrong libsodium lib version (< 1.0.8) or lib not found
ERROR: `/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/libsodium/configure --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php-config' failed

Comment: @apokryfos I have php 8.2.4 but I cannot find sodium.so or libsodium.so file … and also composer install says it requires ext- sodium

Answer (score 0):

From my experience its mainly related to php configuration issue.
You might have enable sodium extension if its disabled since they are bundled with php 7.2.0 onwards.

As a Laragon user insted of wampserver I had to enable sodium extension seperatly for each php version.